# Concept of ArrayBag

Tags: java, autoboxing, bag

I am having trouble understanding a part of class slide that says:

*Storing Items in an ArrayBag :

We store the items in an array of type Object.*

```
public class ArrayBag implements Bag {
    private Object[] items; 
    private int numItems; 
....
}
```

*This allows us to store any type of object in the items array, thanks to the power of polymorphism:*

```
ArrayBag bag = new ArrayBag(); 
bag.add("hello"); 
bag.add(new Double(3.1416));
```

Is ArrayBag a specific type of object or is it just a Obj variable name?
Why do we need to cast 3.1416 as a Double and add a new?
(I know the code could be just be bag.add(3.1416) and Java will autobox it for you, but I'm having trouble understanding the meaning behind bag.add(new Double(3.1416)).

Comment: Are you following this book Data Structures and Other Objects using JAVA??

Comment: This is rather dated; a `Bag` interface should use generics and there's been no need to call `new Double()` since Java 1.5.  I would not rely on this presentation for modern best practices.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is ArrayBag a specific type of object or is it just a Obj variable
>   name?

`ArrayBag` is neither the *specific type of object* not its a *Obj variable*, its actually a **Class**.

> Why do we need to cast 3.1416 as a Double and add a new?

No you need not to explicitly cast  the `double` as `AutoBoxing` comes into picture (Java 1.5 and above) and convert `double` to `Double` ie from primitive to Object.

> I'm having trouble understanding the meaning behind bag.add(new
>   Double(3.1416)

`bag` is actually an instance of  `ArrayBag`, and `add()` is a method defined in this class, which takes a parameter of type `Object` and might be adding it in `items` array, which is nothing but an array of `Object`.